# Linux Как принудительно перекомпилировать ядро

Tags: linux, компиляция, ядро, gentoo, gnumake

Я шел по гайду установки Gentoo:
`cd /usr/src/linux` (это ссылка на сурс ядра)
`make menuconfig`
`make`
Ядро скомпилировалось, но потом я решил внести некоторые изменения в конфиг, его я сохранил через тот же `menuconfig`, но при повторном вызове `make` компилировалась лишь малая часть(похоже изменённая). Как перекомпилирвоать все, даже то,что не имело изменений? Чтобы старые скомпилированные файлы перезаписались новыми.

Comment: @megorit т.е. весь каталог `/usr/src/linux` ? И заново скачать ядро?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/816370/how-do-you-force-a-makefile-to-rebuild-a-target

Comment: *The -B switch to make, whose long form is --always-make, tells make to disregard timestamps and make the specified targets. This may defeat the purpose of using make, but it may be what you need.*

Comment: @megorit о, это полезно! Только вот при вызове make с флагом `-B` он пишет,что `"Configuration file .config not found!"` ,но он есть в это папке, я проверил, да и без флага `-B` он не ругается

Comment: скорее всего вы запусукаете не из каталога, где нахождится `Makefile`